# EJS giving error "Error: property value expected" when used inside a style attribute

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, ejs

I am trying to set a background color on my div based on a a color send down by my server. I can't solve this with classes because the color value could be any legal color value. However, VSCode is giving me an error when I type the following. Is EJS not allowed to use with css related stuff?

```
<div style="background-color: <%= display_color %>;"></div> // Error: property value expected
```

Comment: Okay. so this was presented misleadingly. It's not a compile error- no wonder I wasn't able to reproduce it. This is an ESLint error. Please [edit] to clarify that. Show the eslintrc file for a [mre]. Out of curiosity, why not use `<%-` instead of `<%=` here?

Comment: @user I'm sry but I don't even know what ESList is?

Comment: I'm somewhat astounded that you somehow found a solution to your problem that says eslint in it then :P Here ya go: https://eslint.org/

Comment: @user lol, just stumbled upon it after hours of searching and it magically worked, didnt intent to question why. Also I have always learned that <%= is for variables passed from the server and <%- is for files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ESLint error. ESLint is a linting tool. It can help you find and fix (mostly/usually) stylistic problems with your code. It's highly configurable, and can also be used to auto-fix some problems for you.

As you already found, you can disable the lint warning for a single site/line like so:

```js
<div <% /* eslint-disable css-propertyvalueexpected */ %> style='background-color: <%= display_color %>;'></div>
```

If you want to disable the warning once and for all, create [an ESLint configuration file](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files) and do it there.

If you haven't installed the [ESLint NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint) to use it that way, you're probably getting this because of one of your VS Code extensions.